# What are the different tiers of technology?

Tags: no-mans-sky

All the technology upgrades I've found have a suffix which seems to determine the tier or effectiveness, such as "Tau" or "Sigma". How many of these tiers are there and which is the strongest?

Comment: I've heard that Theta is the most powerful or effective, but I don't know of the other ranks.

Comment: These levels are no longer applicable. They are now labeled (from lowest to highest) C, B, A, S.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are four tiers of tech upgrades: Sigma, Tau, Theta and Omega. Their comparative strengths rank as follows:

Omega > Theta > Tau > Sigma

The stronger the upgrade, the rarer/more expensive the materials required to build it will be, as noted by @David Yell.

As noted by user @SGR, not every tech has four tiers -- four is the maximum you'll see, and the comparative ranks shown above still apply to techs with fewer tiers of upgrades.

([Source](https://m.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4x6xdj/item_levels_theta_omega/), [Source](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/no-mans-sky-recipe-list-crafting-guide-blueprints-and-everything-you-need-know-549944), [Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/739857-no-mans-sky/74149075))

Comment: It's worth noting that the the higher tiers of blueprint require rarer ingredients and greater quantities too.

Comment: Can this answer include the strength of these tiers?  How much of the circle-meter fill up with a tier 3 tech, for example.

Comment: @Carl I'm not sure which circle-meter you're talking about (on holiday right now, so can't boot up the game). I did, however, add the upgrade "numbers" if that helps. Feel free to edit the answer with the information you're talking about.

Comment: User Lockness has said they found a +5.

Comment: @DCShannon Saw that, and found out that the numbers vary between blueprints. Removed modifier numbers from answer.

Comment: Do you need all 4 tiers of an upgrade to get the bonus? I have thetha hyperdrive but won't let me go to blue galixys that need it

Comment: @michael Perhaps your warp drive doesn't have enough warp cells to make the jumps required. I would *assume* that you'd need a cell for each system travelled through.

Comment: Hyperdrive upgrades stack.

Comment: @michael The color of a star system doesn't matter when warping. I've seen no references to needing certain hyperdrives to visit a system. Warpdrive upgrades let you warp farther away and that's it.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I can guarantee that the basic warp drive won't let you warp to a blue star. I don't recall the exact message but it's different from the "too far" one.